# font awesome - hashtag icon don't show

Tags: icons, hashtag

Hi and sorry for my bad english. I'm using icon from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/ in navbar of my new site. Some icon used work very well but the "hashtag" icon don't show in my menu!

How can i solve this? The code is: "fa fa-hashtag" but not work properly!

thanks who want help me. PS: my site it's www.tribeaters.com actually i'm using hashtag via normal font, but i prefer use fontawesome icon

Answer (score 0):

You're using Font-Awesome version 4.3. `fa-hashtag` was added in 4.5. It should be safe to update.